# Python - short syntax and list comprehension and iterations

Tags: python, list, iteration, list-comprehension

I am a big fan of Python's list comprehension and I think it's actually easier to read than a regular iteration.

I am writing a constructor that has optional arguments in `**kwargs` that could be used to set the class' attrs, and I'd like to write it as a list comprehension, but it seems pointless to have a list which doesn't actually do anything.  consider this:

```
class Book(object):
    attrs = ('id', 'title', 'authors',...)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        [setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr) 
              for attr in O.attrs if kwargs.get(attr)]
```

While the syntax looks good, I think this is bad coding because you have created a list of

```
[None, None, None...]
```

that's just sitting out there. And yes granted I know it's collected after the constructor runs, but I still don't like it.  If I read someone's code that had that, I'd be unimpressed.

Is there maybe a better way to do that iteration that's as as clean as a list comprehension but doesn't create useless objects

EDIT:

In response to use the loop

```
class Book(object):
    attrs = ('id', 'title', 'authors',...)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         for attr in attrs:
             if kwargs.get(attr):
                 setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr)
```

Is that what you guys mean?  If not, what a better way to write that?

Comment: Just use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: To check if the key is in the dictionary, use `if attr in kwargs` instead of `if kwargs.get(attr)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a list comprehension, you could use a generator expression, updating the [instance `__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) directly:

```
class Book(object):
    attrs = ('id', 'title', 'authors',...)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(
            (attr, kwargs[k]) for k in kwargs.viewkeys() & self.attrs)
```

This also makes use of [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects); in Python 3, just use `kwargs.keys()` instead of `kwargs.viewkeys()`. A dictionary view acts as a set; the `& self.attrs` expression produces the intersection between the keys of `kwargs` and your list of attributes.

The generator expression produces `(key, value)` pairs, one of the two acceptable inputs for the [`dict.update()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

Updating `self.__dict__` is *just fine*; the Python 2.7 standard library uses this technique in 7 different locations, plus some 30 other cases of mutation. Do take into account that if you are using descriptors (`@property` and / or other custom descriptors) then accessing `self.__dict__` would bypass those.

As for list comprehensions for the side effects: just don't. You are indeed wasting cycles creating a list object that is immediately discarded, confusing expectations as to what a list comprehension is *for*.

You can also combine this with explicit `setattr()` calls, in a regular `for` loop:

```
for attr in kwargs.viewkeys() & self.attrs:
    setattr(self, attr, kwargs[attr])
```

Comment: I've read in multiple places (even here on SO) how one should avoid directly updating `__dict__`

Comment: @SamHammamy: You can use `vars()` if you want to be pure about it.

Comment: @SamHammamy: for what it is worth: the Python standard library has exactly 9 counts of `self.__dict__.update`.

Comment: That's awesome that you either know that, or just grepped it.  Either way: Impressive Sir

Comment: Downvoted - directly setting the instance's `__dict__` is a terrible idea as it will bypass any property or custom descriptor. Martijn you should know better...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: *And that could be the point*. Updating `self.__dict__` is common practice. I'll add a caveat about descriptors, that is indeed something you need to be aware about.

Comment: @martijn updating `self.__dict__` is not that common (9 cases in the stdlib as you mentioned - I wouldn't qualify this as 'common' - and is still a bad practice. Now it's like any "golden rule": you can break it, but only when you really understand when it's OK to break it. Given your (largely deserved) reputation here I'm more than surprised you advise such a solution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I guess we disagree on how golden the rule is then.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: fwiw, I only looked for `__update__` calls, there are at least 30 cases of key assignment in `self.__dict__`, plus one case where `__dict__` is passed to a clean-up function.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for attr in [a for a in attrs if a in kwargs]:
    setattr(self, attr, kwargs[attr])
```

That's reasonably simple and sweet...

Or as Chris recommends:

```
for attr in (a for a in attrs if a in kwargs):
```

would be better. (Generator rather than list)

Comment: `for attr in kwargs.viewkeys() & attrs:`

Comment: Looks even better with a generator.

Comment: Martijn:  That's really concise.  I like it for that.  I always forget about views.  It's a little less obvious though.  I guess if I used views a lot more and could remember stuff like you can `&` a View and a List, but not two Lists, then it would read just as well.